# Angular data with ngModel available in json but not displayed on page load

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

I have an Angualar 4 app with a backend MVC Controller. I have a custom address control which i wish to update to collect a new name. My MVC Model is returning the value on submit and saving to the database but the Angular control is not displaying the new value on page load. Any ideas please?

The Angular address-control-component.ts file

```
constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.addressForm = formBuilder.group({
      "contactperson": [null, Validators.required],
      "line1": [null, Validators.required],
      "line2": [null, null],
      "city": [null, Validators.required],
      "state": [null, Validators.required],
      "postcode": [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

The Address-control.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="addressForm">
  <div class="address">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value.contactperson" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !addressForm.controls['contactperson'].valid && (addressForm.controls['contactperson'].touched || submitted)}"
        formControlName="contactperson" class="form-control" (blur)="onBlur()" placeholder="contact person" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
      />
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="addressForm.controls['contactperson'].hasError('required') && (addressForm.controls['contactperson'].touched || submitted)">contact must be supplied</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value.line1" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !addressForm.controls['line1'].valid && (addressForm.controls['line1'].touched || submitted)}"
        formControlName="line1" class="form-control" (blur)="onBlur()" placeholder="Line 1" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
      />
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="addressForm.controls['line1'].hasError('required') && (addressForm.controls['line1'].touched || submitted)">Line 1 must be supplied</div>
    </div>
```

The Form.component.html

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label>Address</label>
      <app-address-control formControlName="businessAddress" [(ngModel)]="data.businessAddress" [submitted]="workflowSections[0].submitted"></app-address-control>
    </div>
```

form.component.ts

```
this.stationInformationForm = formBuilder.group({
                        "survey.region": [this.data.survey.region],
                        "lesseeNames": [this.data.stationName, Validators.required],
     "businessAddress": [this.data.businessAddress, CustomValidators.addressValidator],
  });
```

The business address object returns all the other properties but not the 'contactperson'. Do i need to set an update flag or something? I thought the NGModel did this?

Comment: In your code i can see you are using both Template Driven Form and Reactive Forms. Just stick to one you wont have to worry about mismatch in the UI and the model

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't mix **formControlName** with **[(ngModel)]**. Only setting the value on the form's controls is enough. Also if you need to listen value chenges you should subcribe to valueChanges over the control as follow

```
this.addressForm.controls.line1.valueChange.subscribe(value => {
    // Do something
})
```

The aim of ReactiveForms is deal with control's behavior by code and in the template only reference it with **formControlName**.

Hope this can help you.